# angular2 inject a service to other - error when using @Inject

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-services

I am using angular2 Beta. and getting error when using the @Inject annotation to DI my one service to another, not able to figure out where I am wrong. Everything seem to be as per  [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/).

I am using a cloud based data-services - CloudDB - for my application's data needs. 
CloudDB gives me a javascript based client library  that I can include in my js app and use to do CRUD operations in my cloudDB database or call other custom API I have stored in my CloudDB account, like UserAuth API (API to authenticate user's credentials). 
Before using cloudDB js client lib API , I need to supply my cloudDB account's URL and authKey by calling CloudDB js object's getClient method.

In my angualar2 app, I created a injectable service class - CloudDBProvider - the would store my CloudDB account URL and authKey and call   CloudDB.getClient to set the provider's js client object for my CloudDB account.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2'; 
///<reference path="../typeDefs/CloudDB.d.ts" /> //typedef of CloudDB js library

@Injectable()
export class CloudDBProvider {
    private cloudDBClient: CloudDB.JSClient; 
    public get cloudDBClient(): CloudDB.JSClient {
        return this.cloudDBClient;
    }


    constructor() {
        this.cloudDBClient = new CloudDB.getClient(
            "https://myaccount.CloudDB.com/",
            "AcfdsfmyDdCMHeadfsdsdfHdsf68" // account authKey
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a UserUtils service in this angular2 app, to which I want to inject above class to get cloudDBClient object. I coded UserUtils service class like below, as learnt from your tutorial

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {CloudDBProvider} from './CloudDBProvider';

@Injectable()
export class UserUtils {
private _userDetails: Object = {};
private _cloudDBProvider: CloudDBProvider;
private _cloudDBClient: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;;

constructor( @Inject(CloudDBProvider) cloudDBPrvdr: CloudDBProvider) {
    this._cloudDBProvider = cloudDBPrvdr;
    this._cloudDBClient = this._cloudDBProvider.cloudDBClient;  //the public getter property in the class CloudDBProvider
}

public authenicateUser(p_strUserName: string, p_strUserPassword: string) {
    var p: Promise<any> = new Promise(
        (resolve: (result: any) => void, reject: (err: any) => void) =>
            this._cloudDBClient.userlogin(p_strUserName, p_strUserPassword).done( //using API 'userlogin' of cloudDB to authenticate user against my cloudDB's users table.
                (loginResult) => {
                    alert("from Userutils - You are now logged in as: " + loginResult.user.basicProfile.firstName);
                    resolve(loginResult);
                },
                (loginErr: any) => {
                    alert("Error: " + loginErr.request.responseText);
                    reject(loginErr);
                }
            )
    );

    return p;
}
```

}

then I am trying to use UserUtils in my LoginPage component like below:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {WelcomePage} from  "../views/welcome/welcome";
import {UserUtils} from  "../services/UserUtils";


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
    providers: [UserUtils]
})
export class LoginPage {
    private _userUtils: UserUtils;

    constructor( userUtils: UserUtils) {
        this._userUtils = userUtils;
     } 


    public loginButtonClicked(event, userName, password) { //called when Login Button is clicked by user
         //...
        //... to-do field value verification 
        //...

        this._userUtils.authenicateUser(userName, password).then(
          (result) => {
              //navigate to WelcomePage
          },
           (err) => { alert(err); }

      );

   }
}
```

the component LoginPage doesn't work when I use UserUtils. The browser console throws error - No provider for CloudDBProvider! (LoginPage -> UserUtils -> CloudDBProvider)

Note that, if I move the 'authenicateUser' method from UserUtils to CloudDBProvider directly and use CloudDBProvider in LoginPage component for user authentication, then everything works just fine, user gets authenticated and navigated to welcome page after login. Also, no error is thrown and app working if I remove @Inject(CloudDBProvider) cloudDBPrvdr from UserUtils's constructor obviously I cannot use CloudDBProvider then in UserUtils, but point is app doesn't throw any error, which means something is wrong with @Inject.

any clue where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Upto my Understanding your mistake is in the imports change the import of `Injectable`with this

```
import {Component, Inject, Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
```

also accoriding to me when we have used `@injectable` annotation no need to use `@inject` in the constructor you simply put your service with the `public` identifier and can use that service into any another method of the same class.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. I'm using Ionic framework, the code snippet I have in my question is to explain what I am doing at high-level. Actual code has some Ionic specific  code. Ionic provides Injectable and Inject from 'angular2/angular2', so there is no mistake in import.  As for injecting the service using public identifier, I had tried that too, but was getting the same error.

Comment: ohh okay i hav't read before that you are usng ionic framework. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add the `CloudDBProvider` provider in the list of providers of your component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
  providers: [UserUtils, CloudDBProvider]
})
export class LoginPage {
  (...)
}
```

Or at application level within the second parameter of the `bootstrap` function:

```
bootstrap(MainComponent, [CloudDBProvider]);
```

This answer could give you some additional hints: [Angular2 Beta dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548347/angular2-beta-dependency-injection/34550615#34550615).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry